# Xpath 1.0 nodelist based on node names

Tags: xpath

I don't like to ask for help, but this time I'm getting totally stuck with a xpath query.

Please have a look at this XML:

```
<doc>
  <car>
    <property id="color">
      <attribute id="black" />
      <attribute id="white" />
      <attribute id="green" />
    </property>
    <property id="size">
      <attribute id="small" />
      <attribute id="medium" />
      <attribute id="large" />
    </property>
  </car>
  <attributes>
    <color>white</color>
    <size>small</size>
  </attributes>
</doc>
```

The car/properties should be output according to the attributes nodenames. The desired output is:

```
<property id="color"><attribute id="white" /></property>
<property id="size"><attribute id="small" /></property>
```

The xpath

```
/doc/car/property[@id=name(/doc/attributes/*)]/attribute[@id=/doc/attributes/*/text()]
```

results only the first node, because the name() function returns only the name of the first element.

Who can help me to find out a working xpath (XSLT 1.0)? Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with XSLT-1.0, but not only with XPath-1.0, because in XPath-1.0 you can only return the first item. This is not a problem in XSLT-1.0, because you can use an `xsl:for-each` loop, like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/doc/attributes/*">
    <property id="{/doc/car/property[@id=current()/local-name()]/@id}"><attribute id="{/doc/car/property[@id=current()/local-name()]/attribute[@id=current()/.]/@id}" /></property>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This code emits the following XML:

```
<property id="color"><attribute id="white"/></property>
<property id="size"><attribute id="small"/></property>
```

As seen, your requirements seem to be a little bit redundant, but I guess that your greater scenario justify the means.

Comment: In fact it's a greater scenario. I broke the problem down to an absolute minimum.

Comment: And that's good. But the relevant question is: does my solution help you. And if not, why not?

Comment: An interesting approach, thank you very much! It will be a day or two before I can determine whether all xpath expressions in the project can be replaced or not.

Comment: :Thanks for the food for thought. That's right, I have to leave xpath and determine the result via XSL. With exsl:node-set() I can then convert the RTF result.
The XSL solution looks very simple.

Comment: @E.Wiest:Many thanks for your three samples. But they do select any matching attribute regardless to the parent property. If the same attribute ID occurs in several properties, there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

What about these options (it's still unclear to me why you're using `name()` since I don't see any namespace in your sample data) :

```
//property|//attribute[@id=//attributes/*]

//attribute[@id=//attributes/*]|//attribute[@id=//attributes/*]/parent::property

//property|//attribute[@id=substring-before(normalize-space(//attributes)," ") or @id=substring-after(normalize-space(//attributes)," ")]
```

Third option should work even if you have to deal with a namespace for the `@id` inside the `attributes` node.

Output :

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

My working solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/doc/car/property">
      <property id="{@id}"> 
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute[@id=/doc/attributes/*[name()=$id]/text()]" />
      </property>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using a loop:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/car/property"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="attribute[@id = /doc/attributes/*[name() = current()/@id]]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For each `property` it copies the element node and its attributes. Then it copies its `attribute` children having an `id` matching the respective element below `/doc/attributes`.