# How to extract only the tag names (not the values) from XML, eventually with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, extract

I get sometimes xml files (every time a completely different one), where I have to extract manually with copy and paste all the tag names, one by one.
Is there a way to get this made more easily, perhaps with XPath online ?
I don't have a lot of knowledge about xml and other programs.
It would be great if I could get some concrete help or some orientation.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Example :
For

```
<item>
<test1>819249</test1>
<test2>asdfasf</test2>
<test3></test3>
</item>
```

I would love to get : 
test1
test2
test3

Comment: To confirm, you only want the 'leaf' tag names? (your list doesn't include `item`)

Comment: Hello and thx, yes I confirm, I would prefer just to get the leaf tag names, and just one of them if they are some duplicates, I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 1):

This selects the names of the nodes:

```
/item/*/name()
```

But it requires [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/). Many tools support only XPath 1.0. If you have only XPath 1.0, you need XSLT, too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138481/xpath-1-0-nodelist-based-on-node-names).